# Is it possible to just transfer these html bootstrap to a react app?

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Let's say I have this in my html project as the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SHOP</title>
    <!--logo-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/logo.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/css/lightbox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#"><img src="assets/shop.png" id="logo"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="index.html">Cakes </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="cart.html">My Cart </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can I just copy paste this directly in my react app? And if so, how? I tried putting all of the stylesheets on the html file on the react app and it does not work.

this is the html file of the react app under public:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="SHOP"
    />
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/css/lightbox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  
URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>SHOP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the header.js

```
const Header = (props) => {

  return (
    <div class="nav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            {/* <a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#">
              <img src="assets/sweetara1.png" id="logo" />
            </a> */}
            <button
              class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navcol-1"
            >
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active" role="presentation">
                <a href="index.html">Cakes </a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="cart.html">My Cart </a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#">Register</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};



export default Header;
```

There's no error but at the same time, it doesn't display all of the link and the designs.

Comment: In react you have to use className instead of class. And have you imported the bootstrap css files?

Comment: yes already did inside the html of the react app under public

Answer (score 0):

You need to use className in the React JS files, not the public html file. Other than that, it looks like you have commented out the navbar link on the top left of the header.

The `header.js` file should look like this.

```
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <a className="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#">
              <img src="assets/sweetara1.png" id="logo" />
            </a>
            <button
              className="navbar-toggle collapsed"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navcol-1"
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li className="active" role="presentation">
                <a href="index.html">Cakes </a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="cart.html">My Cart </a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#">Register</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: I did that, but the bootstrap does not reflect on the design.